# docker desktop & knative & knative func

Tags: docker, kubernetes, knative, faas

i have installed ubuntu 22.04, docker desktop, enabled kubernetes in docker desktop, installed knative serving, installed 'func' but when i do "func build" from terminal gives this error;
"ERROR: failed to initialize docker client: failed to connect to docker socket: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: connection refused"
i did "export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///home/user/.docker/desktop/docker.sock" but didn't help.

how can i change socket address to right one?, knative 'func' is also looking for "dockerd" daemon, if i install it with sudo apt install docker.io it removes docker desktop, what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Your docker is not running. Please try to restart the docker desktop.